# FASM procedure ends with an unauthorized access error

Tags: fasm

I am trying a write a procedure that will read the input of the user and assign input values to the corresponding addresses (trying to create an array dynamically). However, after running the cycle, the program crashes at the ret part. The debugger indicates unauthorized access to DB[0000000]. What am I doing wrong?

```
array_ini:
    lp:
            push temp
            push readnum
            call [scanf]

            mov eax, [temp]
            mov [array + ebx*2], eax

            add ebx,2
            cmp ebx,10

            jl lp

            push done
            call [printf]


    ret
```

Comment: your problem seems not to be your array, it is something on your configuration. Please verify that the account you are using to access the db has the proper authorization.

Comment: @Gi1ber7 I resolved the issue. I wasn't fully aware of the fact, that when we call a function, the return address is pushed into the stack. So when I called scanf, my stack would get emptied and then a 0 would be popped into ESI register and I would get unauthorized access exception for trying to get in there.